# MATLAB interface configuration window pops up while trying to install packages

Tags: apt, software-installation, matlab

I am having an problem while installing any software using terminal, it's always giving me the same error message, it's showing "MATLAB interface configuration error" even I have not installed such MATLAB.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `apt list *matlab* --installed`.

Comment: This is not an error message. The system asks where to install MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need the MATLAB integration to your system, then simply remove this package by

```
sudo apt-get purge matlab-support
```

or forcefully by

```
sudo dpkg -P matlab-support
```